# Can x = 1 for a compound of the form x-methyl-3-hexene?

Tags: organic-chemistry, nomenclature

I came across a question in a textbook *Chemistry Live* by Declan Kennedy:

> Draw the structural formula for the compound 1,3,5-trimethylhex-3-ene.

My issue is with the 1-methyl part. Isn't this compound just the same as 2,4-dimethylhept-3-ene?

I don't think it is a typo as it appears again in an updated version of the same book.

Comment: Yes, it is. Maybe there is a typo as something like **2**,3,5-trimethylhex-3-ene would make sense.